# Is there a word for someone who is your relative but is neither your descendant nor you his?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm writing a function in Python that will allow me to list all folders that have a common root folder (common ancestor), but in the process of building up unordered folder pairs for each folder, I am weeding out all pairs where folder A is a descendant of folder B or vice versa.

In essence, I want to pair each folder with all the other folders **except** all of its children and all of its parents.

So, what do you call a relative who is neither your descendant nor you his?

**More information per request:**

This issue appeared in the field of programming, hence the tag, but I welcome a general answer, if one such exists.

A sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used. Oh boy, this is going to sound contrived.

**Julia is my relative, but she is neither my descendant nor I hers. She is my __insert word here__.**

Comment: I've added the SWR tag, since this is exactly what you're asking for. However, please note that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: Also, you've used the [tag:programming] tag, but I'm not sure that's appropriate, since you appear to be asking for a word that applies generally rather than just in the narrower domain. The tag description says "Questions about English used for talking about programming, but not about programming languages themselves." If you're "talking about programming", please edit your answer to make this clear; if not, please [edit] to delete the tag.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena I'm looking for a word that would encompass {{aunts, uncles, cousins}, n-removed}. As to the second part of your answer: OK, but what is X to Y?

Comment: *Extended family*? *Indirectly related*?

Comment: @JasonBassford I hate to nitpick, but "extended family" could also mean great-great-grandfather, while "indirectly related" is neither a noun nor a single word.

Comment: That's why it was a comment, not an answer, and I provided another suggestion too. Also, you're not going to find a single word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For programming use, a one-word answer could be **non-lineal** (or **nonLineal** in code). A clearer *phrase* would be **non-lineal relative**, or **... relation** (or **nonLinealRelative** etc. in code).

Justification: from [Lineal Descendant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineal_descendant) on Wikipedia:

> A lineal descendant, in legal usage, is a blood relative in the direct line of descent – the children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc. of a person.

being widened from simply *descendent* to *lineal relative* (encompassing parents, grandparents etc.) and then being negated (all those who *aren't* lineal relatives).